# Javascript on click not showing the elements it should

Tags: javascript, html, css

So I a writing a simple flowchart, and I am probably doing this very wrong, but it seems to work the way I have it, design wise. Code wise, I seem to have done something wrong, it is supposed to show 4 elements, the h1,and the 3 div's which show your options, when you click on yes or no, it will show the other elements of it relating to your choice here is my markup and I have run it through http://validator.w3.org/ and it says it is fine.

On line 150 it says I have a syntax error in dreamweaver(program I used)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<style>
body{background-color:#999}
p{color:#0CF}
h1{
    color:#03C;
    text-align:center;
}

#q1{
    position:absolute;
    left:293px;
    top:41px;
    border:thin black solid;
    background-color:#9CF;
    width: 531px;
    height: 72px;
    font-size:64px
}
#q2{
    position:absolute;
    left:424px;
    top:257px;
    border:thin black solid;
    background-color:#9CF;
    width: 62px;
    height: 54px;
    font-size:48px;
}
#q3{
    position:absolute;
    left:633px;
    top:405px;
    border:thin black solid;
    background-color:#9CF;
    width: 186px;
    height: 39px;
    font-size:32px
}
#q4{
    position:absolute;
    left:494px;
    top:145px;
    border:thin black solid;
    background-color:#9CF;
    width: 100px;
    height: 165px;
    font-size:36px
}
#q5{
    position:absolute;
    left:633px;
    top:255px;
    border:thin black solid;
    background-color:#9CF;
    width: 74px;
    height: 55px;
    font-size:48px;
}
#q6{
    position:absolute;
    left:573px;
    top:407px;
    border:thin black solid;
    background-color:#9CF;
    width: 50px;
    height: 39px;
    font-size: 36px
}
#q7{
    position:absolute;
    left:240px;
    top:404px;
    border:thin black solid;
    background-color:#9CF;
    width: 246px;
    height: 41px;
    font-size:36px;
}
#q8{
    position:absolute;
    left:671px;
    top:317px;
    border:thin black solid;
    background-color:#000;
    width: 2px;
    height: 82px;
}
#q11{
    position:absolute;
    left:854px;
    top:453px;
    border:thin black solid;
    background-color:#000;
    width: 5px;
    height: 59px;
    font-size:36px;
}
#q12{
    position:absolute;
    left:449px;
    top:319px;
    border:thin black solid;
    background-color:#000;
    width: 4px;
    height: 78px;
    font-size:36px;
}
#q13{
    position:absolute;
    left:551px;
    top:519px;
    border:thin black solid;
    background-color:#9CF;
    width: 371px;
    height: 44px;
    font-size:36px;
}
#q14{
    position:absolute;
    left:826px;
    top:401px;
    border:thin black solid;
    background-color:#9CF;
    width: 61px;
    height: 44px;
    font-size:36px;
}
#q15{
    position:absolute;
    left:602px;
    top:454px;
    border:thin black solid;
    background-color:#000;
    width: 5px;
    height: 57px;
    font-size:36px;
}
.hidden{
    visibility:hidden
}
</style>
<script>
function show (x) {
        var a=document.getElementById(x)
        a.style.visiblity.visible
</script>
</head>

<!-- ADD IDS TO HIDDEN CLASSES, MAKE FUNCTION TO SHOW THEM ON NON-HIDDEN ELEMENTS -->
<body>
<div id="q1">Should You Worry?</div>
<div id="q2" onClick="show('q7')">No</div>
<div id="q3" class="hidden" >Can you fix it?</div>
<div id="q4"> Do you have a problem?</div>
<div id="q5" onClick="show('q3,q6,q14')">Yes</div>
<div id="q6" class="hidden" onClick="show('q13')">No</div>
<div id="q7" class="hidden">Then don't worry</div>
<div id="q8" class="hidden"></div>
<div id="q11" class="hidden"></div>
<div id="q12" class="hidden"></div>
<div id="q13" class="hidden">Then don't worry about it!</div>
<div id="q14" class="hidden" onClick="show('q13')">Yes</div>
<div id="q15" class="hidden"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You miss a closing paren } at the end of function show()

Comment: Please use semicolons at EOL!

Comment: dreamweaver should get credit for answering this question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

show() needs to be like this:

```
function show(x) {
    var a=document.getElementById(x);
    a.style.visibility = "visible";
}
```

You have to set `visibility` a value, which can be the following[[1]](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/visibility):

- hidden
- visible
- collapse
- inherit

When you use `a.style.visibility.visible`, you are trying to access 'visible' property inside 'visibility', which does not exists. For a complete info about what the style property holds, open firebug/devtools and write `document.getElementById('xxx').style;` (where xxx is an id of an element) on console, which will list you all properties inside style (all of them show as strings).

[image]

For more info, read [MDN HTMLElement.style](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement.style)

---

One thing you should notice is that `show('q3,q6,q14')` is trying `document.getElementById('q3,q6,q14')` which does not exist (looking for something like `<element id="q3,q6,q14">`). For that use:

```
<div id="q5" onClick="show('q3');show('q6');show('q14');">Yes</div>
```

Or you can change the `show()` to something newer (but at the cost that [does not support IE7](http://caniuse.com/queryselector)):

```
function show(x) {
    var a=document.querySelectorAll(x);
    for(var i=0;i<a.length;i++){
        a[i].style.visibility = "visible";
    }
}
```

And use with CSS selectors, which then accept `,`:

```
<div id="q5" onClick="show('#q3,#q6,#q14');">Yes</div>
```

If you need to support IE7 below, [Sergio's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18991472/684932) will suffice.

Comment: Thank you very much, quick question if you have the time and see this, if I want <div id="q2" onClick="show('q7')"">No</div> to show multiple elements, would i write it like <div id="q2" onClick="show('q7,q8')">No</div> or would I make it <div id="q2" onClick="show('q7')" onClick="show('q8')">No</div>   ?

Comment: @Jeffperlmutter Just added more info about the multiple calls on answer.

Answer (score 0):

This line:

```
a.style.visibility.visible
```

Should set the style with an `=`

```
a.style.visibility = 'visible';
```

Comment: @andi -- Bah, what's one "i"? :) Fixed.

Answer (score 0):

Since you send many parameters into show() like `show('q3,q6,q14')` you could use this:

```
function show(x) {
    x_arr = [];
    x_arr = x.split(',');
    for (i = 0; i < x_arr.length; i++) {
        var a = document.getElementById(x_arr[i]);
        a.style.visiblity = 'visible';
    }
};
```